# Heated rod utilizing super position

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I am trying to solve the heat equation 
$$ u_t=u_{xx} $$
with $$u(0,t)=0, u(1,t)=100, u(x,0)=\sin(\pi\,x), 0<x<1$$

obviously one solution is $100\,x$ for $u(0,t)=0, u(1,t)=100$, and I am supposed to use superposition to come up with a series solution.

my initial reaction is to consider this like a neumann problem letting
$$u_x(1,t)=0, u_x(0,t)=0$$ and using seperation of variables to get
$$u_n(x,t)=\cos(n\,\pi\,x)e^{n^2 \pi^2 t}$$
Then utilizing super position I can rerwrite my solution as

$$
u(x,t) = a_0/2 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(n\,\pi\,x)e^{n^2 \pi^2 t} +100x $$

keeping in mind that for $x=1$ the terms other then $100x$ go to $0$ as the $a_n$   and $a_0$ are picked in a way that for $u(x,0)$ we get $\sin(n \pi \,x)e^{n^2 \pi^2 t} + 100x$ which is $0+100x$. thus satisfying the initial condition 
I still feel as if I messed up as it does not satisfy $u(x,0)=\sin(\pi\,x)$

maybe I pick my $a$ values differently?
Or maybe pick $100x$ to be $100 \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a picecewise function that is 0 everywhere except x=1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why Neumann boundary conditions? Let $u=v(x,t)+100\,x$. Then $v$ satisfies the heat equation $v_t-v_{xx}=0$ with boundary and initial conditions
$$
v(0,t)=0,\quad v(1,t)=0,\quad v(x,0)=\sin(\pi\,x)-100\,x.
$$
The solution will be of the form
$$
v(x,t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n\,e^{n^2\pi^2t}\sin(n\,\pi\,x).
$$

Comment: Was thinking neumann, as if I take the derivative of my boundary conditions, I can make them homogeneous which I know how to solve

Comment: You cannot take the derivative of the boundary conditions: there is no $x$ in $u(0,t)=0$.

Comment: I see, thankyou

Comment: if you dont mind, could you explain to me why I cannot take the derivative of $u(0,t)=0$ by using separation of variables I have $X(0)T(t)=u(0,t)$ so wouldn't we assume any derivative of this would be 0?
(sorry I dont have any experience taking derivatives of boundary conditions I only saw it as a potential way to get the problem into a familiar form)

Comment: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(0,t)\ne\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigl(u(0,t)\bigr)$$